# PDB Oracle DB ORA-40365

Tags: oracle

The essence of the problem is this. I'm trying to open pluggable database but it opens with Warning: PDB altered with errors. An error occurs in pdb_plug_in_violations (Sync PDB failed with ORA-40365 while performing 'alter user sys account lock pas sword expire'05-FEB-22 03.01.33.629000 PM) about password sen for user sys and ws (created manually). I changed the passwords and did everything as it is written, but I can’t open the database normally. Tried a bunch of methods and nothing. How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to reset SYS's password.

1. Switch to root container.

   ```
    SQL> alter session set container=CDB$ROOT;

    Session altered.
   ```
2. Expire SYS's password for all containers.

   ```
    SQL> alter user sys password expire container=all;

    User altered.
   ```
3. Set a new password for SYS.

   ```
    SQL> alter user sys identified by "&lt;password&gt;" account unlock;

    User altered.
   ```

Then test the result.